# Python 2.7 replacing all values in a pandas DF

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

in a pandas dataframe: everything I try replaces the key,value pairs in the first column, but not in the first and second. Here is the code:

```
module_names = {442990: 'Thank You', 442896:'Depression', 442924:'Irritability', 442879:'Anxiety', 442985:'sleep', 442875:'Meds'}
for key, value in module_names.iteritems():
    df['module'].replace(key,value,inplace=True)
print df.head(15)
for key, value in module_names.iteritems():
    df['inResponseTo'].replace(key,value,inplace=True)
print df.head(15)
```

And the output:

```
        module inResponseTo botNickname  botID result  \
1      Thank You       442896   Web-Ducky  36931      4   
3     Depression       442924   Web-Ducky  36931      4   
5   Irritability       442879   Web-Ducky  36931      3   
7        Anxiety       442985   Web-Ducky  36931      4   
9          sleep       442875   Web-Ducky  36931    yes   
11          Meds       442875   Web-Ducky  36931    NaN   
13          Meds       442864   Web-Ducky  36931    NaN   
19     Thank You       442896       Ducky  36931      3
```

You can see I am not even trying to be terse, but I'm breaking it out to see if I can spot my error. Right now I'm stumped. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC if need replace values in some column by `dict` simpliest is remove loop:

```
df['inResponseTo'].replace(module_names,inplace=True)
print df
          module  inResponseTo botNickname  botID result
1      Thank You    Depression   Web-Ducky  36931      4
3     Depression  Irritability   Web-Ducky  36931      4
5   Irritability       Anxiety   Web-Ducky  36931      3
7        Anxiety         sleep   Web-Ducky  36931      4
9          sleep          Meds   Web-Ducky  36931    yes
11          Meds          Meds   Web-Ducky  36931    NaN
13          Meds        442864   Web-Ducky  36931    NaN
19     Thank You    Depression       Ducky  36931      3
```

And if need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) (where not match get `NaN`):

```
df['inResponseTo'] = df['inResponseTo'].map(module_names)
print (df)
          module  inResponseTo botNickname  botID result
1      Thank You    Depression   Web-Ducky  36931      4
3     Depression  Irritability   Web-Ducky  36931      4
5   Irritability       Anxiety   Web-Ducky  36931      3
7        Anxiety         sleep   Web-Ducky  36931      4
9          sleep          Meds   Web-Ducky  36931    yes
11          Meds          Meds   Web-Ducky  36931    NaN
13          Meds           NaN   Web-Ducky  36931    NaN
19     Thank You    Depression       Ducky  36931      3
```

EDIT:

If need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) in multiple columns:

```
print (df)
          module  inResponseTo botNickname  botID  result
1      Thank You        442896   Web-Ducky  36931  442896
3     Depression        442924   Web-Ducky  36931  442924
5   Irritability        442879   Web-Ducky  36931  442879
7        Anxiety        442985   Web-Ducky  36931  442985
9          sleep        442875   Web-Ducky  36931  442875
11          Meds        442875   Web-Ducky  36931  442875
13          Meds        442864   Web-Ducky  36931  442864
19     Thank You        442896       Ducky  36931  442896

df[['inResponseTo','result']] = df[['inResponseTo','result']].replace(module_names)
print (df)
          module  inResponseTo botNickname  botID        result
1      Thank You    Depression   Web-Ducky  36931    Depression
3     Depression  Irritability   Web-Ducky  36931  Irritability
5   Irritability       Anxiety   Web-Ducky  36931       Anxiety
7        Anxiety         sleep   Web-Ducky  36931         sleep
9          sleep          Meds   Web-Ducky  36931          Meds
11          Meds          Meds   Web-Ducky  36931          Meds
13          Meds        442864   Web-Ducky  36931        442864
19     Thank You    Depression       Ducky  36931    Depression
```

Comment: Sorry I still get the same result. No error just the first column changed. BTW, trying to paste my code in but it is not working, sorry.

Comment: Your code works, if I apply it to the first column, but any attempt to change the 2nd column leaves me stymied.

Comment: BTW just deleted the column 'module' and it still does not work, is there a key word of something in the 2nd col: 'inResponseTo' ?

Comment: Hi, tried the new code: df[['inResponseTo','module']] = df[['inResponseTo','module']].replace(module_names)

only replaced module column, not the 'inResponseTo' column

Comment: Maybe there is different dtype like string instead int. So need `df['inResponseTo'] = df['inResponseTo'].astype(int)` for convert to int first.